# How to manage/preserve file privileges during an online file transfer?

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

I was thinking if it is possible to make an script to send to a friend to fix some problems on his computer. I want to give executable permissions to a file so my friend just have to double-click in the file, something like this:

https://github.com/fletom/ACLr8

But when I use the `chmod a+x` with my file and I send the file to my friend (in this case I send it to myself), he (I) cannot execute because the file has lost the `+x` permissions.

Is there a way (there is, the man of the link is able to do it) to send a bash script with executable permissions just to double-click and execute it?

Comment: How did you send the file?

Comment: `sh` files can't be double-clicked to execute. They need to be run from the Terminal. Eg: `/path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: I sent the file by mail!

Comment: It's your friend, the person who's going to run it, who should be doing the `chmod`, unless you transport the script by some mechanism which preserves file attributes. Mail doesn't.

Comment: @muru which I explained and basically described in my answer below.  XD   Perfect timing coincidence :)

Comment: your friend can always run the script with `. /path/to/script` or `bash /path/to/script` , assuming it is a bash script of course.

Answer (score 8):

> NOTE: The question at the time addressed Email transfer (per comments from the OP on the question).  This answer is written to address that question as it was, in that email is the transfer method available here.

When using **email** to transfer files between systems, you can't 'preserve' all the file permissions as you want them to be when just sending the file.  This is because it's a 'new download' that is a 'new file' created per the terms and requirements of the system policy for 'new file creation permissions' in the download location, on the download system, etc.  This is also because email protocols do not have any mechanisms to outwardly preserve the permissions from the source system.

The GitHub example you show will 'save' the permission states for the files as a part of the version control system.  Email doesn't have that mechanism.

---

Since we've established that Email does not let you preserve file permissions as such, you need to evaluate other methods.

1. *Use a tarball*.  You can create a directory with the file in it, and create a tarball to hold the system.  When extracted on a Linux system, it will try and 'preserve' those permissions as things were when you zipped up the files.  `tar -pczf name_of_your_archive.tar.gz /path/to/directory` is the general command structure to use.  However, if they can't run `tar xzf` or similar on the other end, this won't work.
2. *Use a Version Control System to hold the data, such as a GitHub repository.*  You could create a github repository to hold the shell script, then have the other person clone it down to their system.  This *should* preserve the executable bit, but no guarantees.
3. *Instruct the other user in how to set the executable bit via the command line*.  If they download the file to `/home/USERNAME/Downloads`, where `USERNAME` is their username, you can then instruct them to login to the terminal and run `chmod a+x /home/USERNAME/Downloads/FileName.sh`, and then they can run it by double click or by the command line.
4. **If email is the only transfer option**, then *run the script with the shell language you wrote it in (likely Bash, is my guess)*.   This won't need any changes to the permissions or the execute bit anywhere.  **Assuming that this is a Bash script**, then, simply have the remote user who downloaded the script execute the following (from the Command Line): `bash /path/to/script.sh` (and replace `/path/to/script.sh` with the actual file path, likely `/home/USERNAME/Downloads` or a default email download location or if downloaded via webmail in a web browser where USERNAME is the user's username)

Other than the first three methods, which I am aware of, I don't believe you will be able to 'preserve' the permissions when sending the file to the other user.  This is a limitation of Email - it can't preserve permissions in that way, because there's no way to save the permissions as part of that file in a way that is preserved during the transport over email.  The fourth option gives a method to not even *need* the executable bit and not mess with permissions at all.

Comment: +1..although if the friend is willing to run in command line, the execute bit is not needed..he could do `bash script.sh`

Comment: @heemayl doh, forgot about that, however, we can't always be certain the shell script is a bash script - there are other shell languages, such as `zsh`.  Added it anyways, though.